# Ruby regex return array of numbers only

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex

I have the following strings:

```
1: "AMETHYST 9.5x10.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"

2: "AMETHYST 9x10 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"

3: "AMETHYST 9-10 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"

4: "AMETHYST 9.5-10.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"

5: "AMETHYST 9.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"

6: "AMETHYST 9 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"
```

Per case I would like my regex to return an array of the integers or floats for example taking the first case:

```
[
  [0] "9.5"
  [1] "10.5"
]
```

After much trying on Rubular I came up with:

```
/\d+[.]\d+?/
```

This gives me most of the match results I need when checking on Rubular.com. However in the cases 2, 3, 6 it will not pickup on the integer in front of the - or x character, or when the int is alone like case 6.

What am I missing?

THANKS!

Comment: Are the prefixes "1:, 2:, 3:" in the data?  Or just for labeling the lines?

Comment: **Note to everyone**. The question is: "**What am I missing?**" So far, only Nishu's and my answers answer this question.

Comment: This isn't Jeopardy, you can phrase the answer any way you like. Working examples that solve his problem with regex or other alternatives are still useful answers. Besides "What am I missing?" is more of an expression, not a specific request.

Comment: Only the OP can determine what answers the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def doit(str)
  str.scan(/\d+\.?\d*/)
end

doit "AMETHYST 9.5x10.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA" #=> ["9.5", "10.5"]
doit "AMETHYST 9x10 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"     #=> ["9", "10"]
doit "AMETHYST 9-10 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"     #=> ["9", "10"]
doit "AMETHYST 9.5-10.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA" #=> ["9.5", "10.5"]
doit "AMETHYST 9.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"      #=> ["9.5"]
doit "AMETHYST 9 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"        #=> ["9"]
```

Comment: `#scan` -- That's it. No argument.

Comment: @Arup, actually, it does take an argument.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing to make the period character optional. That can be done by using the quantifier `?`.

By the way, it is not clear why you need to make the fractional digit non-greedy. You did not explain that you only want a single digit below the decimal point. Furthermore, it does not make sense to use it together with the quantifier `+` as in `\d+?` in this case; it would have the same effect as `\d`.

To make it work, you can have a regex like this:

```
/\d+\.?\d*/
```

or

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/
```

Comment: Suppose the OP wanted to extract all strings that begin with one or more digits, possibly followed by at most one period, and if a period is present, it must be followed by one or more additional digits. What regex would you use for that?

Comment: @CarySwoveland My second regex will do that.

Comment: Your second regex returns ["9.5", "10"] for "AMETHYST 9.5x10. OVAL".  What I meant is what regex would return `["9.5"]` for that string; i.e., disregard `10.` because no digits follow `10.`.  Just curious.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I see. What about  `/\d+\.\d+|(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)/`?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things missing in the regex.

First: Make the dot character as optional by using a ? following it.
Second: Make value following dot as optional and dynamic length by adding *

```
\d+[.]?\d*
```

Comment: Using `[.]` is the long way around to escape `.`. Instead, use `\.`.

Comment: Agreed. Continued the convention in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your example input is accurate, I'd use `scan`, since that's what it's made for, and massage the results a tiny bit to only return the values you want:

```
strings = [
  '1: "AMETHYST 9.5x10.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '2: "AMETHYST 9x10 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '3: "AMETHYST 9-10 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '4: "AMETHYST 9.5-10.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '5: "AMETHYST 9.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '6: "AMETHYST 9 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
]

strings.map{ |s| s.scan(/\d+[.\d]*/)[1..-1] }
# => [["9.5", "10.5"],
#     ["9", "10"],
#     ["9", "10"],
#     ["9.5", "10.5"],
#     ["9.5"],
#     ["9"]]
```

`/\d+[.\d]*/` means "Find one or more digits, optionally followed by any number of `'.'` and digits. That'll match the leading `1:`, but slicing the array strips those. If numbers existed like `1.0.0.0` the pattern would return `1.0.0.0` but that's a pretty nonsensical value for this sort of output so I think the pattern is reasonably safe.

If the example input isn't accurate, and the line numbers didn't really exist then it becomes more simple:

```
strings = [
  '"AMETHYST 9.5x10.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '"AMETHYST 9x10 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '"AMETHYST 9-10 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '"AMETHYST 9.5-10.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '"AMETHYST 9.5 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
  '"AMETHYST 9 OVAL CHECKERBOARD AAA"',
]

strings.map{ |s| s.scan(/\d+[.\d]*/) }
# => [["9.5", "10.5"],
#     ["9", "10"],
#     ["9", "10"],
#     ["9.5", "10.5"],
#     ["9.5"],
#     ["9"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on Rubular for the examles you provided:

```
\d+(?:[.]\d+)?
```

Simply put a non capturing group around the last part and placed your last ? on the outside making it a 0 or 1 instead of a lazy quantifier.